# jqGrid's search filters are not loading in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, advanced-search

I am trying to implement advanced search using JQGrid and MVC4. The definition of my model seems to be fine (as below):

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string sidx { get; set; } 
    public string sord { get; set; } 
    public int page { get; set; } 
    public int rows { get; set; } 
    public bool _search { get; set; } 
    public string searchField { get; set; } 
    public string searchOper { get; set; } 
    public string searchString { get; set; }
    public FilterModel filters { get; set; }
}
public class FilterModel
{
    public string groupOp { get; set; }
    public List<RuleModel> rules { get; set; }
}
public class RuleModel
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string op { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

However when I run and search for UserName and FirstName, the receiving controller shows filters as null. Then I checked (Request.Params)["filters"], it shows the following text -

```
"{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"UserName\",\"op\":\"eq\",\"data\":\"a\"},{\"field\":\"FirstName\",\"op\":\"eq\",\"data\":\"b\"}]}"
```

and it shows _search is true. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Could you post the full json request that you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, but how to get the JSON? I am using JQGrid's URL option for specifying the action and nothing else.

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Comment: Yes, that too didnt work. When I change the filters to string, it is populating the content. But I want as an object.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correct the request contains an anonymous JSON object (without any name) so in your controller you can't pass one `SearchModel` argument, you will have to add all the arguments explicitly :

```
ActionName (string sidx, string sord, int page, ..., FilterModel filters)
```

An alternative could be writing custom model binder (which is quite simple) that will wrap your request params into a single SearchModel object.

Comment: Indeed it is working for all other options. Simple search is working fine. But just the advanced search that causing the issue.

Comment: Post the query string that you are getting in the request (Request.QueryString)

Comment: I think something to do with HTML Encode... I am getting the QueryString as: _search=true&nd=1410081961485&rows=10&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&filters=%7b%22groupOp%22%3a%22AND%22%2c%22rules%22%3a%5b%7b%22field%22%3a%22IsActive%22%2c%22op%22%3a%22eq%22%2c%22data%22%3a%22true%22%7d%5d%7d

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem which you have is that `filters` parameter will be send by jqGrid in *another way* as all other parameters. You can define it as `string` and make conversion to `FilterModel` from JSON manually (using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FilterModel>(filters)` of `Newtonsoft.Json` or using `serializer.Deserialize<FilterModel>(filters)`, where `JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();`). It seems to me the most easy way. You can of cause use custom model binder of MVC, but you will have at the end the same results.

Alternatively you can try to change the value of `filters` parameter which send jqGrid

```
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    var dataToSend = $.extend({}, postData); // make copy
    if (dataToSend.filters) {
        dataToSend.filters = $.parseJSON(postData.filters);
    }
    // the last statement can be not needed and one should just use
    //     return dataToSend;
    // instead. If one do convert the data to JSON as in the line below
    // one should use ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }
    // option of jqGrid to set the corresponding ContentType HTTP header
    return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
}
```

I don't tested the above code, but I think that it could work.

Additionally I want post some common remarks.

You need implement server side paring and filtering **only for really large** dataset. In case of having less as 1000 rows of data for example I prefer to use `loadone: true` parameter and return *all data* at one to the client. Filtering of such set of data *on the client side* work really good (and even more quickly as server side filtering) and you will need don't write any server code for filtering. So: don't try to use sever side filtering on small dataset.

The next remark. If you use only Advanced Searching then you can remove `searchField`, `searchOper` and `searchString` parameters. "Simple" searching is legacy model.

The next remark: default names of parameters which send jqGrid is not the best: `sidx`, `sord`, `_search`. One can use `prmNames` parameter of jqGrid to *rename* almost all parameters send by jqGrid. For example if you would use `prmNames: {sort: "sortIndex", order: "sortDirection", search: "isSearching"}` you can rename `sidx` to `sortIndex`, `sord` to `sortDirection` and `_search` to `isSearching` in `SearchModel`.

The last remark. If you really need to implement server side filtering of data you can consider to implement the *full* model described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options). It includes `groups` part together with `rules`. The `groups` part will be filled if you would use `multipleGroup: true` option together with `multipleSearch: true`.